# Magento-2.3: Multishipping Tablerates Issue

Tags: magento2.3.2, table-rates, multishipping

I have setup fresh Magento 2.3.2 - configured tablerates for Multi-shipping.

It seems while selecting the shipping Method its showing rates properly.

but after selection and going to next step its not showing properly,
it's showing last selected rates for every shipping address. Please Help..

> Checkout:

[image]

> Order Overview:

[image]

> Tablerates:

[image]

> Cart:

[image]

> Wrong amount in `quote_address` Table:

[image]

Comment: its cache issue, verify with total address amount

Comment: It's not cache issue, i have checked in database wrong shipping_amount.

Comment: If you look at the address you will see that in step 1 and step 2 are different so im assuming the price is based on postcode or region please provide an example of step 1 and step 2 with the same address

Comment: @DavaGordon i have updated my question.

Comment: @DavaGordon someone has raised the issue in Magento: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23631